# Windows filepath converted to Linux filepath

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, paths

I have a Windows path in a bash variable as a string:

```
file='C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'
```

I am trying to convert this path into a Linux path starting with `/c/Users...`.

**My attempt**

The following works:

```
file=${file/C://c}
file=${file//\\//}
echo $file
> /c/Users/abcd/Downloads/testingFile.log
```

**Problem**

Here, I have done this for a string that contains the filepath. The reason I am asking this question is that I have to convert 20 such strings in a bash script in Ubuntu 16.04 and each time I do this I have to write 2 lines per conversion - it is taking up a lot of space!

**Question**

Is there a way to combine the 2 commands

```
file=${file/C://c}
file=${file//\\//}
```

into one command?

Comment: Use a for loop (and maybe an array). Also quote your variables.

Comment: Thanks. Could you show an example of how to do this in a loop or array?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There would be a way to do both replacements at once using `sed`, but it's not necessary.

Here's how I would solve this problem:

1. Put filenames in array
2. Iterate over array

```
filenames=(
  'C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'
  # ... add more here ...
)

for f in "${filenames[@]}"; do
  f="${f/C://c}"
  f="${f//\\//}"
  echo "$f"
done
```

If you want to put the output into an array instead of printing, replace the `echo` line with an assignment:

```
  filenames_out+=( "$f" )
```

Comment: Ok.But if I had 2 files `f1` and `f2`, how would that work? I mean, how do I re-assign the new filenames to the array by replacing the old ones?

Comment: @WR put em in a new array and use that.

Comment: @WR Added that into the answer

Comment: I'd recommend to make a new array, for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 10):

If it's something you want to do many times, then why not create a little shell function?

```
win2lin () { f="${1/C://c}"; printf '%s\n' "${f//\\//}"; }

$ file='C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'
$ win2lin "$file"
/c/Users/abcd/Downloads/testingFile.log
$ 
$ file='C:\Users\pqrs\Documents\foobar'
$ win2lin "$file"
/c/Users/pqrs/Documents/foobar
```

Comment: That's not a bad idea. However, it does not seem to give `/c/Users...` - instead it is giving `C:\Users\...`.

Comment: @WR apologies - copy-paste error. Please try it now.

Comment: Thanks, I use `cdw () { f="${1/D://d}"; cd "/mnt${f//\\//}"; }` in Windows subsystem for Linux, works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You would be able to achieve this in one line using sed

```
file="$(echo "$file" | sed -r -e 's|^C:|/c|' -e 's|\\|/|g')"
```

Note the two patterns must remain separate nonetheless as the matches are replaced by different substitutions.

Comment: Synonym: `file="$(sed 's|^C:|/c|; s|\\|/|g' <<< "$file")"`

Answer (score 1):

Is this question still open to new suggestions? If so, would this help you?

```
$ file="/$(echo 'C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'|tr '\\' '/')"
$ echo $file
/C:/Users/abcd/Downloads/testingFile.log
```

Oh, and in case the C must be cast to lowercase:

```
file="/$(echo 'C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'|tr '^C' 'c'|tr '\\' '/')"
```

As an overview:

```
$ file='C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log'
$ echo $file
C:\Users\abcd\Downloads\testingFile.log
$ file="/$(echo $file|tr '^C' 'c'|tr '\\' '/')"
$ echo $file
/c:/Users/abcd/Downloads/testingFile.log
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `'^C'`?

Comment: ^ means start of the line,  otherwise all occurences of C will become lowercase... should there be any

Comment: I must add that the other suggestions also work. Many Unix command can do the same work, so  its up to you what style of solution you prefer use.

Comment: I had not asked earlier about `^` that has been used in some other answers here too. Thanks for the answer and the explanation.